# Aggregate and plot time series in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date, plot, time-series

I have a dataframe with date as index. I want to count events aggregated bi-weekly and plot. Example:

```
date        id
2018-01-01  a1
2018-01-01  a2
2018-01-05  a3
2018-01-12  a4
2018-01-15  a5
2018-01-17  a6
2018-01-19  a7
...
```

Should appear as (the format is ilustrative, if I am able to discriminate then it is fine ):

```
2018-01-1   4
2018-01-2   3
...
```

Then plot.

If possible, I want a parameter so I am able to switch to weekly or monthly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If date is the index, you can use [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html#pandas.DataFrame.resample) with the SemiMonthStart ('SMS') frequency:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.resample('SMS').count()
```

Output:

```
            id
date          
2018-01-01   4
2018-01-15   3
```

You can also use [date offsets (here `SemiMonthBegin`)](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.SemiMonthBegin.html#pandas.tseries.offsets.SemiMonthBegin) to round your dates and use this result to `groupby`+`count`:

```
group = (pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
           .apply(pd.offsets.SemiMonthBegin().rollback)
           )

out = df.groupby(group)['id'].count()
```

Output:

```
date
2018-01-01    4
2018-01-15    3
Name: id, dtype: int64
```